# Why do Technic beams have an odd number of holes?

Tags: technic, piece-information, history

Why do LEGO Technic beams tend to have an odd numbers of holes?
Is it for making it suitable for designing models? Or does the owner of The LEGO Group love either odd or even numbers?

Answer (score 12):

It's to make them fit with the original Technic bricks which have an even number of studs and the holes go in-between.

[image]